# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. when using Invoke-RestMethod from Azure powershell runbook

Tags: json, azure, powershell, httprequest

I'm trying to send Microsoft Azure Alerts to Google Chat room (Hangouts) from within Azure Powershell Runbook. From time to time the message is sent without any issues, but roughly in half of the tries it returns the error below:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. 
At line:43 char:1 
+ Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uriHangouts -Method Post -body $body -Content ... 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Line 43 of my script looks like this

```
Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uriHangouts -Method Post -body $body -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Where $uriHangouts is the webhook address and the $body is message according to the schema provided here:
https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/basic

As it is testing only, I'm sending every time exactly the same message. It is a basic one with some markup.
If I forward it to Azure Logic App and resend it from there to Hangouts, it works every time.
If I send it from my PC, it works every time as well.
So far, I've tried without any success to use Invoke-WebRequest instead Invoke-RestMethod, and force TLS 1.2 (1.1) with the following line:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

I'm literally out of ideas where to go next.

Please, help!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 16):

You do not need to use `Invoke-WebRequest` instead `Invoke-RestMethod`, you just need to run `​[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` before executing `Invoke-RestMethod` as [this blog](https://evotec.xyz/invoke-restmethod-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-send-while-connecting-graph-api/) mentioned.

And if you want use `Invoke-WebRequest` instead `Invoke-RestMethod`, you can have a try with add `-UseBasicParsing` after `Invoke-WebRequest` command.

Answer (score 4):

After months of exchanging emails with Microsoft, it is officially confirmed bug. Below is their response.

Resolution:
We have identified this issue as a platform bug and we are working on it.

Upgrading the Automation Account Platform version is going to happen
This is a major change for Automation and it will take few months to roll this out, but at this moment we cannot provide an ETA for the same.

In the mean time as a workaround, they are suggesting to implement a retry mechanism in the runbook as the issue is happening intermittently.
​

Comment: Do you have any tracking page ( may be github issue ) where Microsoft is maintaining the status??

Comment: @Sasho Zahariev, if you have any more info on this issue, it would be good. I'm not 100% certain this is the problem I have seen. I use devices that for testing use a self-signed cert, although this can be ignored using `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}` in Windows PS 5.1, and the `-SkipCertificateCheck` in PS 7. 

I then see this issue in WIn PS 5.1 for an `Invoke-RestMethod` request to a specific device but ONLY using the `GET` method. Things are fine using a `POST` method to the same device. In PS 7, there is no issue.

Comment: FWIW, I just ran a couple of PCAPs using Win PS 5.1 issuing an `Invoke-RestMethod` command using the `GET` vs `POST` method. In both cases, Win PS 5.1 uses TLS 1.2 (1.3 is supported by the server device, but never offered by Win PS). The `Client Hello`, `Server Hello` and Certificate exchange all work well, and then the server sends a TLS message containing `Change Cipher Spec Protocol` and `Handshake Protocol`. With the `GET` method, Win PS immediately sends a `FIN ACK`, but with the POST method, things progress as expected. 

So, its the Win PS client that terminates the connection.

Comment: I thought I would create a post on the MS forums, although I think this should be a perhaps be GitHub issue - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1049779/odd-issue-with-invoke-restmethod-in-windows-ps-51.html